# Why does AVCaptureDevice.default return nil in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I've been trying to create my own in-built camera but it's crashing when I try to set up the device.

```
func setUp() {
        do {
            
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output) {
                self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

When I execute the program, it crashed with the input because I try to force unwrap a nil value which is device.
I have set the required authorization so that the app can use the camera and it still end up with a nil value.

If anyone has any clue how to solve the problem it would be very appreciate

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for a `builtInDualCamera`, i.e. [one that supports](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype/2727142-builtindualcamera):

- Automatic switching from one camera to the other when the zoom factor, light level, and focus position allow.
- Higher-quality zoom for still captures by fusing images from both cameras.
- Depth data delivery by measuring the disparity of matched features between the wide and telephoto cameras.
- **Delivery of photos from constituent devices (wide and telephoto cameras) from a single photo capture request.**

And you're requiring it to be on the **front** of the phone. I don't know any iPhone that has such a camera on the front (particularly the last one). You likely meant to request `position: .back` like in the [example code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-default). But keep in mind that not all phones have a dual camera on the back either.

You might want to use `default(for:)` to request the default "video" camera rather than requiring a specific type of camera. Alternately, you can use a [AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/discoverysession) to find a camera based on specific characteristics.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm currently using a iPhone 11 and even when I'm using the back camera it crashes. I used the ```default(for:)```and it solved the problem but I was wondering how when could change the position of the camera ?

Comment: With `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession` you can specify the location along with what types you can accept. Or you can chain together multiple `default` checks to find what what you want. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/choosing_a_capture_device  See particularly their `bestDevice(in:)` example.